# VueJS2 How to change the order of components based on a radio selection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to make the order of my blue (script 1) and red (script 2) labels change based on what radio I selected. For example, when I select radio 1, I want the order of the labels to show: blue, red, blue, red, blue, red. If I select radio 3, I want the order of the labels to show: blue, blue, blue, red, and so on.

I am lost on how to make the change for the blue and red labels, as it is very dynamic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Joshua, can you show your code so we can see what you have tried? I have some opinions on how to do it, but without seeing how you have structured it currently, it's tough to help. Show the minimal amount of code needed (template and script for the buttons)

Comment: Use a computed property to create the labels. Based on what is selected, change the order, and then render that. Without any sample code, it is frankly impossible to help you come up with a solution

Comment: @Jtcruthers https://i.imgur.com/73diz9m.png https://i.imgur.com/fWulRQF.png https://i.imgur.com/EJvUp1J.png -- first 2 are from the template and the last is for the script. Apologize for the limited view.

Comment: @SuitBoyApps https://i.imgur.com/73diz9m.png https://i.imgur.com/fWulRQF.png https://i.imgur.com/EJvUp1J.png -- first 2 are from the template and the last is for the script. Apologize for the limited view.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code in text format. I’d suggest looking at the how to ask help article first, maybe browse some other upvotes questions. This way we have a better chance at helping you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask